# Style something when something else is checked

Tags: jquery, css

Example as follows:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <span class="radio">
       <input type="radio" class="input_radio" >
    </span>
    <label class="color_btn">
    <div class="inner_value"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

In the above example, i need when input is checked to use box-shadow to the div with class=inner_value. Any ideas on this?

Comment: I believe it is not possible with CSS alone, since CSS has no `parent` selector.

Comment: If its possible with jquery or javascript i don't mind if anyone posts a solution with this

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: It helps if you show us what you've tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pull the `input` out of the `span`, then you can do this with CSS alone using a sibling selector.

```css
input:checked + .color_btn .inner_value {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <input type="radio" class="input_radio" >
  <label class="color_btn">
  <div class="inner_value">inner_value</div>
  </label>
</div>
```

And here is a way to do it using javascript by adding an event handler to the `input`, then assigning a class for the shadow.

```js
document.getElementById('radio').addEventListener('click',function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('inner_value')[0].classList.add('shadow');
});
```

```css
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
    <span class="radio">
       <input type="radio" class="input_radio" id="radio">
    </span>
    <label class="color_btn">
    <div class="inner_value">inner_value</div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Michaels' answer, this is a javascript approach that also works with check boxes

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("input_radio")[0].onchange = function() {
      if (this.checked === true)
          document.getElementsByClassName("inner_value")[0].style.boxShadow = "2px 2px 5px #888888";
      else
          document.getElementsByClassName("inner_value")[0].style.boxShadow = "";
    };
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
    <span class="radio">
       <input type="radio" class="input_radio" >
    </span>
    <label class="color_btn">
    <div class="inner_value">example</div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well of course it's possible with jQuery:

```js
$(".input_radio").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).closest('.control-group').find('.inner_value').addClass('has-shadow');
  }
});
```

```css
.has-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">
  <span class="radio">
       <input type="radio" class="input_radio" >
    </span>
  <label class="color_btn">
    <div class="inner_value">Inner value div</div>
    </label>
</div>
```